# Trouble consolidating a jQuery menu animation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some animation effects that shrink certain divs on the page when a menu item is clicked. This allows for more screen space for the end user in certain areas of the main page.

I have the function working, but I'd like to consolidate it a bit. Below is my code:

```
$('#wp-tabbed-widget-2').click(function () {
    $('.site-title').animate(
        {fontSize: "16px"},
        200);
    $('.title-area').animate(
        {width: "200px",
         paddingLeft: "10px"},
        400);
    $('.site-header').animate(
        {minHeight: "50px"},
        400);
    $('#header-logo').animate(
        {width: "40px",
         paddingLeft: "10px"},
         400);
});
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is this -
The code above works fine for one menu item, but I have 3 more I'd like to apply this to (let's say #wp-tabbed-widget-2, ...3, ...4). I don't want to copy/paste this code above and just change the attributes to match the new button, as that seems lazy and messy.

I know I need to write some sort of condition to monitor which button is clicked in order to do this, but the mechanics of that are escaping me right now. What would be the best way for me to go about writing something nice and neat?

Comment: can you show your html code?

Comment: If you're using multiple divs like the one above, make sure you differentiate the IDs for the `header-logo` element so you don't have multiple logos with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#wp-tabbed-widget-2,#wp-tabbed-widget-3,#wp-tabbed-widget-4').click(function () {
    $('.site-title').animate(
        {fontSize: "16px"},
        200);
    $('.title-area').animate(
        {width: "200px",
         paddingLeft: "10px"},
        400);
    $('.site-header').animate(
        {minHeight: "50px"},
        400);
    $('#header-logo').animate(
        {width: "40px",
         paddingLeft: "10px"},
         400);
});
```

Just put commas between the ID's

Comment: Don't you need a `this` or a child selector in there, to only target the divs in the clicked widget?

Comment: if the elements referenced inside the click function are specific to each item as well then yes, but based off the question and titles of the classes it didn't seem like that was the case.